# LocalStrategy is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, passport.js

I'm using *passport.js* for *authentication*, and trying to setup a local strategy. However, whenever I run my code I get an error saying `localStrategy` is not a constructor.

*Code*:

```
// config/passport.js

// load all the things we need
var localStrategy   = require('passport-local');

// load up the user model
var User            = require('../app/models/user');

// expose this function to our app using module.exports
module.exports = function(passport) {

// =========================================================================
// passport session setup ==================================================
// =========================================================================
// required for persistent login sessions
// passport needs ability to serialize and unserialize users out of session

// used to serialize the user for the session
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user.id);
});

// used to deserialize the user
passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
        done(err, user);
    });
});

// =========================================================================
// LOCAL SIGNUP ============================================================
// =========================================================================
// we are using named strategies since we have one for login and one for signup
// by default, if there was no name, it would just be called 'local'

 var authenticate = User.authenticate();
 console.log(authenticate);
 passport.use('local-signup', new localStrategy(authenticate));


};
```

When I run the app, I get:

```
TypeError: localStrategy is not a constructor
    at module.exports (/home/ubuntu/workspace/config/passport.js:38:35)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/workspace/server.js:19:29)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:389:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:504:3
```

If you look here
https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport-local
They do use new `LocalStrategy`. And I have another app that uses this too, and it works =S

Help?

Comment: I copied the code here too https://scotch.io/tutorials/easy-node-authentication-setup-and-local#toc-handling-signupregistration ... same error

Comment: Javascript is case sensitive. Try `new LocalStrategy(...)` (note the capital `L`)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You just missed including Strategy in your require

Change

`var localStrategy   = require('passport-local');`

to

`var localStrategy   = require('passport-local').Strategy`;